# pandas: filter group by multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, multiple-conditions

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
  {'id': 123, 'date': '2016-01-01', 'is_local': True },
  {'id': 123, 'date': '2017-01-01', 'is_local': False },
  {'id': 124, 'date': '2016-01-01', 'is_local': True },
  {'id': 124, 'date': '2017-01-01', 'is_local': True }
])
df.date = df.date.astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

I want to get a list of all the IDs for which `is_local` was True at the start of 2016, but False at the start of 2017. I've started by grouping by ID:

```
gp = df.groupby('id')
```

Then I've tried this just to filter by the second of these conditions (as a way of getting started), but it's returning all the groups:

```
gp.apply(lambda x: ~x.is_local & (x.date > '2016-12-31'))
```

How can I filter in the way I need?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
d1 = df.set_index(['id', 'date']).is_local.unstack()
d1.index[d1['2016-01-01'] & ~d1['2017-01-01']].tolist()

[123]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing this is through [pivoting](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
In [24]: ids_by_dates = df.pivot(index='id', columns='date',values='is_local')

In [25]: ids_by_dates['2016-01-01'] & ~ids_by_dates['2017-01-01']
Out[25]: 
id
123     True
124    False
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the datetime module from datetime library and pass multiple conditions for the dataframe

```
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame([
  {'id': 123, 'date': '2016-01-01', 'is_local': True },
  {'id': 123, 'date': '2017-01-01', 'is_local': False },
  {'id': 124, 'date': '2016-01-01', 'is_local': True },
  {'id': 124, 'date': '2017-01-01', 'is_local': True }
])
df.date = df.date.astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Use multiple conditions for slicing out the required dataframe

```
a = df[(df.is_local==True) & (df.date<datetime(2016,12,31) & (df.date>datetime(2015,12,31))]
b = df[(df.is_local==False) & (df.date<datetime(2017,12,31)) & (df.date>datetime(2016,12,31))]
```

Use pandas concatenate later

```
final_df = pd.concat((a,b))
```

will output you rows 1 and 2

```
    date        id  is_local
2   2016-01-01  124 True
1   2017-01-01  123 False
```

In single line as follows

```
final_df = pd.concat((df[(df.is_local==True) & (df.date<datetime(2016,12,31) & (df.date>datetime(2015,12,31))], df[(df.is_local==False) & (df.date<datetime(2017,12,31)) & (df.date>datetime(2016,12,31))]))
```

Comment: Thanks - how would I use this to get all rows for which `has_local` is True at start of 2016 and False at 2017?

Comment: I could only think of a dirty solution where u add multiple conditions and concat them togeother.. Edited my answer accordingly..

Comment: I also edited my answer with another condition to confine the year to 2016 and 2017 respectively